# Which knock box do you use and why?

Tags: espresso, espresso-machine, coffee-machines

I've been using a repurposed plastic box next to my espresso machine as my go-to knock box, but recently wrote a guide on [knock boxes](https://www.filterbrew.com/espresso-machines/espresso-knock-box/). I'm curious if you can recommend any particular knock box? They all seem universally the same and universally expensive.

Comment: Honestly, knock boxes are in my opinion only necessary in a commercial setting. At your house, just dump it straight in the trash or keep using your plastic box. That seems like a great alternative and does the job just as good. It seems a bit pretentious to buy a knock box for 5 espressi that people make at home a day...and I say that having probably 10 different brewing devices at home :).

Answer (score 1):

Osaka, Shock-Absorbent Espresso Knock Box 4.7 Inch Barista Style Knockbox.

about $20 anywhere online

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. There are many good quality knockboxes. You can find many reviewed on sites like [Coffeegeek](http://coffeegeek.com/proreviews/quickshot/grindenstein) or of course, [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WHC89M).

Knockboxes are practical and make it a pleasure to make espresso. I bought mine based on good reviews and after using it a few months consider it a great purchase.

It's made out of a good grade of tough plastic and can be found [around $20](https://www.seattlecoffeegear.com/grindenstein-knock-box-for-espresso-grounds) online or even less. Rubber coated knock bar and a well thought out cutout on the front for ease of access. Available in red, black and a few other colours. The stainless model is closer to $50 but is elegant if you prefer stainless and would stand up to genuine commercial use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use a Cafelat Tubbi Knock Box in small because it's cheap and a nice size. If I was going to replace it I'd get a Rattleware Maple Knock Box because it's solid and beautifully constructed, plus it's quite handsome.